# Posting Json to WebApi - deserializing to XmlNode

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm sending a JSON object using angular's `$http.post()`.

The Id value is populated, among others.  However, the XmlNode properties are NOT de-serializing, and are null.  This same configuration entity is serialized to json without issue.

### How can I have the XmlNodes deserialized properly?

**Note:** I can't change the configuration class. Also, I'm using the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver Json Formatter.

**Web Api Controller**

```
[Route("api/config/{Id}")]
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Save(Guid Id, Configuration config)
{
    ... config.Configuration is null ...
    return Ok();
}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
public class Configuration {
  public string Id { get; private set; }
  public XmlNode Configuration { get; private set; }
}
```

**Json Data:**

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "configuration": {
        "Config": {
            "Settings": {
                "Setting": [
                    {
                        "@SettingId": "1",
                        "@Name": "DEFAULT"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I have verified that the XML serializes correctly when an XmlDocument is used rather than an XmlNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom `JsonConverter` that converts an `XmlNode` to an `XmlDocument`.

```
public class XmlNodeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(XmlNode);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        XmlDocument document = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonObject.ToString());

        return document;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Adding the converter to the `JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings`

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new XmlNodeConverter());
```

This works, but seems like a hack.  Is there a better way?